# How to auto advance a PowerPoint slide after an exit animation is over?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, vba, microsoft-powerpoint-2003

PowerPoint entrance animation set up with "Start: With Previous" starts right when a new slide is advanced. However, if you set up an exit animation in the same way, it doesn't start with a slide ending sequence. Instead, the "Start: On Click" trigger needs to be used and **after your exit animation is over you still need one extra click just to advance to the next slide**.

**Workaround**s to this are obvious: create a duplicate slide, make your ending animations from the original slide being your starting animations on the duplicate slide and let them be followed with whatever you want or create a transition slide with those ending animations only and set up "Change Advance slide -> Automatically after -> [the time it takes your animations to finish]".

These workarounds will make it work for your audience, visually. However, it has an impact on slide numbers you might need to adjust accordingly and/or duplicate content changes. If you are the only one creating and using your presentation, this might be just fine. But if you are creating a presentation in collaborative mode with three other people and don't even know who will be the presenter at the end, you can mess things up.

Let's be specific: most of my slides have 0.2s fly in entrance animation applied to blocks of content coming from right, bottom or left. Advancing to the next slide I want them to fly out in another 0.2s exit animation being followed by new slide 0.2s fly in entrance animation of the new blocks. The *swapping of the blocks* should be triggered while advancing to the next slide, as usually.
As mentioned, I'm not able to achieve this without one extra click between the slides.

I wrote a **VBA script** that should start together with an exit animation and will auto advance a slide after 0.3s when the exit animation is over. That way I should get rid of those extra clicks which are needed right now.

```
Sub nextslide()
iTime = 0.3
Start = Timer
While Timer < Start + iTime
DoEvents
Wend
With SlideShowWindows(1).View
    .GotoSlide (ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex + 1)
End With
End Sub
```

It works well when binded on a box, button or another object. But I can't make it run on a single click *(anywhere on the slide)* so that it could start together with the exit animation onclick trigger. Creating a big transparent rectangular shape over the whole slide and binding the macro on it doesn't help either. By clicking it you only get the macro running, exit animation is not triggered.
Anyway, I don't want to bind the macro to any other workaround object but the slide itself.

Anyone knows **how to trigger a PowerPoint VBA script on slide onclick event?**
Anyone knows a secret **setting that will make the exit animation work as expected i.e. animating right before exiting a slide while transitioning to the next one?**
Anyone knows how to beat this dragon?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but here's another possible workaround:

Go to: Slide Show, check "Use Rehearsed Timings, then click on "Rehearse Timings", then, during rehearsal, right after the end of the first slide, click as soon as you wish to make the second slide appear, then save changes for your rehearsed timings.

(other related comments [here](http://help.wugnet.com/office/Automatically-advance-slide-custom-animation-finished-ftopict1178330.html))